# Some information need to be displayed above the background image

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I want to display some information(TextView) above the image. When i display the Textview over the image, the background image disturbs the text. So i want to make the background image (faded) so that it won't disturb the TextView. How can i achieve this ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/cor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Some information"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: can you post your code so that it can help in figure out the actual issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setalpha method to the imageview and make the appearance dull.

**set alpha below api level 8**

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.4f, 0.4f);
anim.setDuration(50);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
<view>.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: setAplha(float) was added in new API but my min sdk version is 8. Is there any other method ???

Comment: Thank you so much. It was bothering me the whole day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use alfa animation on your image.
Using `Animation` in android or using [Nineoldandroid](http://nineoldandroids.com/)